# ADO 2.5 calling SQL Server stored procedure returning blank data from scalar function

Tags: sql-server, vb6, ado

I have a legacy app written in VB6 talking to a SQL Server 2008 database using ADO 2.5. Within it is a report that gets data from a stored procedure. The stored procedure calls a UDF that returns a `varchar` result as one column of the result set. When it is called from SQL Server Management Studio it correctly populates that column, but when it is called from within the VB6 application it returns an empty value. Are there any compatibility issues that might be causing this?

Here is the UDF:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.TransferNoteAgreementSummary(@ClientID int, @Year int) 
RETURNS varchar(3000) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret varchar(3000)
    SET @ret=''

    SELECT @ret = @ret +  
        + CONVERT(varchar, F.NumBins) + ' of ' + B.[Name]+', '+CONVERT(varchar, F.DaysPerWeek)+' lifts, ' + CF.Frequency 
        + ' from ' + CONVERT(varchar, F.StartDate,106)+' to '+CONVERT(varchar, F.EndDate, 106) + dbo.CrLf()
    FROM Accounts A
        JOIN AccountFragments F ON A.AccountID=F.AccountID
        JOIN BinTypes B ON A.BinTypeID=B.BinTypeID
        JOIN ContractFrequencies CF ON F.FrequencyID=CF.FrequencyID
    WHERE A.ClientID=@ClientID AND A.ContractYear=@Year
    ORDER BY B.[Name], A.AccountID, F.StartDate

    RETURN @ret
END
```

Here is the relevant part of the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_PrintRoundsReport]
AS

          DECLARE @Year int
    DECLARE @Results TABLE([Route] VARCHAR(100), Town VARCHAR(200), ClientID INT, Customer VARCHAR(400), [Address] VARCHAR(MAX),
                                                    [Item Code] VARCHAR(50), Bins INT, [Type] VARCHAR(40), Volume INT, BinDesc VARCHAR(3000), 
                                                    CollectDay VARCHAR(20), DayOrder int)

[ irrelevant lines removed ]                                                    

    SELECT [Route], Town, Customer, [Address], [Item Code], Bins, [Type], Volume, 
        dbo.TransferNoteAgreementSummary(ClientID, @Year) AS BinDesc, CollectDay
    FROM @Results
    ORDER BY DayOrder, [Route], Town, [Address], Volume
```

And finally, here is the code being called:

```
  Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
  Set cmd.ActiveConnection = GetConnectionString() 

  cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  cmd.CommandText = "sp_PrintRoundsReport"

  Dim rs As New Recordset

  Call rs.Open(cmd)
```

The problem seems to be with the function. If I change it to return a constant string then the value is passes through correctly

Does this ring any bells for anybody?

Comment: I would suspect a permissions issue on the tables in the function.

Also, verify that the function is getting the values being passed to it.

Comment: I tested the UDF parameters earlier, by returning them as the start of the return value. They were correct. Table permissions are all fine as well - these tables are all commonly used from the same app

Comment: SET NOCOUNT ON in the sproc as the 1st line. Problem go away?

Comment: Already got nocount on - been hit by that when returning temp tables before.

Comment: We have a "workaround" of sorts, by the way. I've implemented the report under reporting services for them, so the users are happy. Same stored proc works fine there

Comment: Does any of fields in the result in your function return a NULL value? If so, then your whole varchar variable will be NULL. No matter how many text you add. Use ISNULL() on all fields to work around this problem.

Comment: No, all fields are non-nullable. The users are all pretty happy with the reporting services workaround (which uses the same SQL, by the way, and gives good results), so we've not spent much more time on it

Comment: Did you try using SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF on your stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Don't u are missing?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE")
```